# POST to API using JavaScript returns 401

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am posting data to a web API. The response is a 401 error. I don't know what is wrong with my code.

This is the code:

```
var form = document.getElementById("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var edition= document.getElementById("edition").value;
  var competition= document.getElementById("competition").value;
  var price= document.getElementById("price").value;
  var firstname= document.getElementById("firstname").value;
  var lastname= document.getElementById("lastname").value;
  var email= document.getElementById("email").value;


  fetch("https://front-api.njuko.com/partner/registration", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
    edition: edition,
    competition: competition,
    price: price,
    firstname: firstname,
    lastname: lastname,
    email: email,
      
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
});
```

As i am new to the programming i don't how i can send the data into the website. This are the request sample of the website.

```
{
  "edition": "5d888c93df85b80006f54265",
  "competition": "5d888c93df85b80006f54265",
  "price": "5d888c93df85b80006f54265",
  "firstname": "John",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "email": "john.doe@acme.com",
  "methodName": "Partner payment (VISA)",
  "datas": [
     {
      "value": "Detroit, Michigan",
      "field": "5d888c93df85b80006f54255"
    }
  ],
   "metaData": [
    {
      "key": "stravaActivityId",
      "label": "strava-activity-id",
      "value": "329859FNENF29492Ifnjnfe93"
    }
  ]
}
```

[This are the Actual Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOP3w.png)

Comment: The screenshot has an authorizations section which you don't appear to have done anything about for your fetch request (so a 401 error, meaning you aren't authorized, isn't surprising).

Comment: 401 means you're unauthorized.

Comment: but can you show me how the actual code would be with authorization?

Comment: i don't know where to put the authorization on the part of the code. 

i have the authorization token on for the code.

Comment: You put a header like so : `"Authorization": "Bearer <token>"`

Comment: Read how [authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) typically works, and research documentation for the API that you are using.

Comment: FYI in JavaScript, you do not need to write `{ price: price, firstname: firstname }`, you can simply write: `{ price, firstname }`.

Comment: thanks men. i am really a beginner on programming thanks for correcting me

Comment: yo man, i tried to put authorization headers on the code but this message shows up

why when i tried to enter the token this shows up

error: "Internal Server Error"
message: "An internal server error occurred"
statusCode: 500

do you guys have any idea what does this mean and what changes should i make?

Comment: You probably did it wrong

Answer (score 0):

401 Error Code means Unauthorized.

I don't see any authentication in your code.

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 401 Unauthorized response status code indicates that the client request has not been completed because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the requested resource.

I dont know the implementation of the exact API,
but mostly used is this :

```
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
       "Authorization": "Bearer <API_TOKEN>"
    }
```

Comment: yeah and i don't know where to put it on the actual code as i am looking for solution different kind of solutions are showing and i don't what i would follow. as i stated i am new to programming

Comment: You probable should use : 

    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
       "Authorization": "Bearer <API_TOKEN>"
    }

Comment: why when i tried to enter the token this shows up, the token looks correct then i add the authorization header

error: "Internal Server Error"
message: "An internal server error occurred"
statusCode: 500

Comment: do you know what does it mean? and what changes should i make?

Comment: Try to send the request via POSTMAN and see if this fits up.
As i said in the answer, i dont know the implementation of this API, but reading the documentation is also helpful.

Comment: i am using javascript es6 module for developing the code, i don't know how to use the postman. i also don't know how to read the documentation i mean how to understand the documentation. can you tell where would i start on understanding how the documentation regarding the api works?